# Obtaining all structure constants of $ \mathfrak{su}(N) $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to understand certain properties of general curves $\textrm{Ad}_{e^{t X}} = e^{t ad_X}$ of adjoint-representation matrices of $SU(N)$. For this purpose, I would like to have an explicit closed-form expression for all structure constants $f_{abc}$ of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ for arbitrary $N$ in the form $[T_a, T_b]=f_{abc} T_c$. Ideally, I would like to have them for the usual choice of basis $\{T_a\}$ with the convention that all $T_a$ are traceless, anti-Hermitian and trace-orthogonal, with standard Dynkin index $ tr(T_a T_b) = - \frac{1}{2} \delta_{ab} $, in which $f_{abc}$ is totally antisymmetric.

Is there a reference where such expression can be found? Otherwise, I am more or less familiar with the machinery of the Cartan classification. What would be the best way to attack the problem?

Comment: Well, as you know  from SU(3), the antihermitean basis for the fundamental is not so clean, but it does [generalize readily to SU(N)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Pauli_matrices). However, if you forfeit antihermiticity, you have a celebrated clock-and-shift basis with *analytic* trigonometric structure constants, which is the language most prefer for large *N* systematics... Do you want details?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I have read through the article you reference, and am wondering why I had not heard about these Sylvester matrices before. The construction seems very neat and I suppose all structure constants easily follow from the equation for $(\Sigma_1)^k (\Sigma_3)^j$. However, these are a basis for $\mathfrak{gl}(N,\mathbb{C})$. Is trivial to relate the structure constants of these to those of $\mathfrak{su}(N)$ generators? Yes please, I would really appreciate more details and references if you have!

Comment: Yes... late 19th century. S was a genius. The structure constants are simple *sin* es. Indeed, the algebra of gl(N) up to conventions amounts to that of su(N), and can fit the other ones, with suitable linear combs, as [we did in that basis](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.528788).  The mother of all classical Lie algebras, indeed..... You might start with an easy antique [talk of mine](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/9tahoe.pdf).